# TreeGrid how to check/uncheck all child sublevels checkboxes when marks parent

Tags: jqgrid, checkbox, treegrid

I have built treeGrid with embedded checkbox in column "name", such as JSON data :

```
{"id":"1","name":"<input type='checkbox' class='itmchk' ><strong>ECHANGEUR<\/strong>","level":"0","parent":"null","isLeaf":false,"expanded":true,"loaded":true}
```

because these checkboxes follow tree margins (I hope I'm fine understood because I'm french).

I would like to check/uncheck sublevels checkboxes when I mark/unmark one row but after reading may posts, I can obtain the expected result.

Explanation for example :
  If I click on parent row checkbox (so it become UNCHECKED), sublevels rows become UNCHECKED

I'm newbie with jqGrid but it is a great tool whose I want to learn properties.
Please can you drive me in this way ? Or can you suggest where I can find examples for that I want to do ? I had a look for documentation but without success.

Many thanks in advance
JiheL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I recommend you don't place HTML fragments inside of JSON data. One can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to include checkboxes inside of grid cells:

```js
formatter: function (cellvalue) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' class='itmchk' ><strong>" +
        $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellvalue) + "</strong>";
}
```

To control checking/unchecking of the checkboxes you can use `beforeSelectRow` callback of the grid. jqGrid bound internally `click` event to the grid body. So is no event handler exists directly on the element the [event bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow) take place. It allows to catch checking/unchecking of **any checkboxes** inside of one `beforeSelectRow` callback. Inside of `beforeSelectRow` you should first test whether it was click on a checkbox which you want to control.

Callback `beforeSelectRow` has two parameters: `rowid` and the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/). The property `target` of the event object will be the DOM element which was clicked by user. Because you add your custom `itmchk` class to every such checkboxes it will be enough to verify the class on the clicked element.

The next problem is that many jqGrid method which works with TreeGrid like [getNodeChildren](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid#methods) has `record` as the input parameter, but you have only `rowid` instead. jqGrid save loaded items of the grid locally. So the simplest way to get `record` from the `rowid` is to use `getLocalRow` method.

As the result the code of `beforeSelectRow` callback could be the following:

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        isLeafName = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "treeReader").leaf_field,
        localIdName = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "localReader").id,
        localData,
        state,
        setChechedStateOfChildrenItems = function (children) {
            $.each(children, function () {
                $("#" + this[localIdName] + " input.itmchk").prop("checked", state);
                if (!this[isLeafName]) {
                    setChechedStateOfChildrenItems($this.jqGrid("getNodeChildren", this));
                }
            });
        };
    if (e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" && $(e.target).hasClass("itmchk")) {
        state = $(e.target).prop("checked");
        localData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
        setChechedStateOfChildrenItems($this.jqGrid("getNodeChildren", localData), state);
    }
}
```

It's important to mention that children checkboxes will be checked/unchecked only on previously loaded items. Because you load the data of the grid at once and use `loaded: true` property then it's not problem for you.

The corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2132268_.htm) shows that the above code really works. It's modification of the demo which I created by answering on your previous question.

Comment: I thank you very much for your help you are certainly a master with jqGrid as you know many things about it. Thank you again for all you share with new users. I wouldn't bother you anymore, but following to the above question, I have not tell about radio button which replace sometimes the checkboxes, according to database level value. Is there some way to test the value of another cell in formatter so I can choose radio button or checkbox to be added to cell ? I think that it is beginner's level but I don't see how I can do it. Thanks again for your help. JiheL

Comment: Please don't spend time with my previous comment, I found solution to replace checkbox by radiobutton according level value from database. Many thanks again for your kind patience. Have a nice day JiheL